# Launch GCP instance from my PC using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Which python library should i use to control or launch or delete an instance on my Google cloud platform from my private PC ?

Comment: There are instructions on how to do this by using Python and the REST API. See this link https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage

Comment: This is a tutorial on how to create an instance with the Compute Engine Python client library https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide#addinganinstance

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to use the Google Compute Engine Python API Client Library. [You can see a sample with examples here.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide)

You can see the complete list of functions regarding instances in [REST Resource: instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances)

As you can see, you might do:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')

listInstance = compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone).execute()
stopInstance = compute.instances().stop(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance_id).execute()
startInstance = compute.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance_id).execute()
deleteInstance = compute.instances().delete(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance_id).execute()
```

> Don't confuse the param name "instance" with the chosen name  for the path parameter "resourceId". You can see on the right side or at the bottom of the page examples with the real parameter's name.

You also could directly call the the REST API ([see example](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage)) with in Python if you prefer to using POST/PUT methods.

You also might want to use OAuth. As you can see in the examples of the links provided, it would be something like:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Project ID for this request.
project = 'my-project'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# The name of the zone for this request.
zone = 'my-zone'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# Name of the instance resource to start.
instance = 'my-instance'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

request = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
response = request.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out [libcloud](https://libcloud.apache.org/).